# jquery trigger alert on mouseleave

Tags: jquery

For whatever reason this has successfully eluded me. I'm trying to call an alert when the mouse is no longer hovering the list items while also preventing it from firing when I hover over any space between items that css might create.

JQUERY

```
$('.tinylist li').mouseleave(function(){
  alert("moved");
});
```

HTML

```
<ul class="tinylist">
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: do you want it to be fired when you move from one li to another one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.tinylist').mouseleave(function(){
  alert("moved");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tinylist">
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

define the event for the ul instead list items this way it will not trigger at spaces between list items.

Comment: This would be ideal if hovering specifically over each li wasn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("mouseleave",'.tinylist li',function(){
  alert("moved");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try the event `.mouseout()`

```
$('.tinylist li').mouseout(function(){
  alert("moved");
});
```

If you want to detect when the mouse is out of you're list use `$('.tinylist')`

The two events work well with me :

https://jsfiddle.net/uu87tj77/